# Cropped image in table

Tags: css

I am imploding image through css i looks like this:
[click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqcf9.png)

But I want it to look like this:
[click here to see what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiguV.png)

Image is in td tag

Here is css code:

```
a#id {
    background: url('maps.jpg') no-repeat right center;
    padding-right: 70px;
}
```

EDITED:
html code:

```
<td colspan="2"><a href="#" id="id" target="_blank" style="display: none"><span class="label">Text </span></a></td>
```

Comment: Add your HTML code too

Comment: @Aman yes image now displays properly but it overlaps with text

Comment: do you want image on left side or right side??

Comment: I want it on the right side of the text

Comment: in your screenshot it's on left can you send screenshot how its look after adding below code

Comment: Posted. Not sure if you can see the text

Comment: Add as many padding-right as the width of the photo is

Comment: You could just set your background image size to `contain` and then adjust your table cell height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add padding on top and bottom also. Try below code

```
a#id {
    background: url('maps.jpg') no-repeat right center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-right: 70px; /* padding-right = width of the photo */
}
```